# backup used on device

Tags: adb, backup

Is there a way to tell if a backup file .ab has been used on a android device? Like a log that shows the a back up was used on the device?

I apologize as I am a novice with Androids and ADB, I am trying to find out this answer for work.

Comment: Android has by default no persistent log (except for some kernel messages). `adb logcat` uses a rolling buffer which means depending on the number of messages this buffer will be overwritten in hours or days. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230503/2241 BTW: by "using" do you mean a backup creation or restore? May be you should tell use why you want this information, there may be other ways to get it or to prevent what you don't want to happen.

Comment: I would like to see if a back up .ab restore file was used on the device.