# Proof that mobile data was disabled

Tags: mobile-data, roaming

I have a (rooted) smartphone running Android 7.1.2 and need to prove that over a certain period of time in the recent past (period of a few weeks within the last month), mobile data was disabled and roaming was disabled.

If I could extract from the phone a log of exactly when mobile data / roaming were enabled and when they were disabled, this would already be sufficient proof.

Is such a log available anywhere and is there any way to retrieve it?

Comment: Android has no persistent logs. Only `logcat` exists but depending on it's configured buffer size and the number of messages per minute old entries are overwritten after some minutes up to several days.

Comment: A similar question: [Is it possible to somehow understand from the logs what happened to the phone a month ago? Are there such logs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230503/is-it-possible-to-somehow-understand-from-the-logs-what-happened-to-the-phone-a)

Comment: The Android UI has a panel which shows a graph of mobile data usage and displays the total mobile data usage over a period whose duration is one month and whose beginning date is configurable. This, at least, is some information which my smartphone knows. Unfortunately the graph is too imprecise, I would like to access the actual underlying numerical data, this would already be something useful.

Comment: Another problem is that VoLTE uses a data connection for LTE  and 5G phone/voice transmissions (otherwise the phone has to fall back to 2G or 3G). More details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248997/mobile-data-disabled-but-data-is-still-using-mobile-data/249081#249081

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment there, so let me ask here: are you saying that when mobile data is disabled, it is normal for a smartphone to transfer a little bit of data every now and then because of VoLTE _even if not a single call is ever emitted or received_? If this is so, is it normal for a service provider to charge for data roaming costs for such data transmission even when calls are neither emitted nor received and both mobile data and roaming are disabled?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I don't know if the fault is on device or on MNO side (or on both?) but you can get charged for mobile data just because of VoLTE. I have a data plan with 500MB free so this problem occurred last time when I was abroad where I had to use roaming (where my data plan has no free volume). I directly got charged for a few KB every day, but when talking to my MNO I got the money back.

Comment: Thanks very much for your useful comments. Just for the record, I am still interested in my original question, especially in extracting from the phone the history of data usage (which at least per day is recorded in some log somewhere since data usage can be displayed as a graph).

Comment: Try `adb logcat` or `adb logcat -b events` or `adb logcat -b radio` and enable/disable mobile data. May be you find an entry shows you when data usage was enabled or disabled. Especially the latter could contain this information. But as every phone has a different RIL it is unforeseeable what data you get.